# App does not run with image uploaded on android

Tags: android, image, delphi

I'm using Delphi xe7 with update 1 in an android application that includes an image. When I load the image in the TImage component, the application hangs. When I shoot the image leaving only the component, the application works. I do not know what else to do. Help me please.

Comment: are you use TThread or TTask for image loading?

Comment: please show us sample code of what you are doing. Without this we can have no clue.

Comment: What type image are you using?
For testing only, try convert the image to another format (BMP, JPG, PNG,...) and try to load. 
Same error?